# Open new window after click using QT

Tags: qt, qwebkit

I am trying to implement a simple browser myself using QT, but I got one question now, I wanna to open a new window after clicking a link on a web page, how to realize this function ? How to make `QWebView::createWindow()` work together with `QWebSetting:JavascriptCanOpenWindows` ? I know I should use js to realize "open new window", but how to let the browser capture this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect QWebView's signal **linkClicked** with a slot which opens new window.

For example:

```
connect(ui->webView, SIGNAL(linkClicked(QUrl)), SLOT(openNewWindow(QUrl)));
```